# Locating Dynamic CSS Elements using CSS Selector

Tags: html, css, element

I'm using a product called Stonly to place tool tips. In there, we are to use the CSS Selector to find the HTML element to identify the tool tip. Based on the user's input, they will be provided with a dynamic task list.  I'm trying to locate an element for a particular task, when the location of a particular task may be the 26th task based on one user's input, or the 25th tasks based on a different input.  Each task has a unique data element associated

For example

```
<a data-beacon-article-modal="5ffe3f6fc64fe14d0e1fa33f">Follow-up with your Lender.</a>
```

When I use the CSS Selector

This is what it looks like for one user's input (this task is the 26th task in the list)

```
#root > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.container > div > div > div > div:nth-child(26) > div.accrd-cont > p:nth-child(1) > a
```

This is the selector when I change the input slightly (task becomes the 25th task in the list hence the "div:nth-child(25)".

```
#root > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.container > div > div > div > div:nth-child(25) > div.accrd-cont > p:nth-child(1) > a
```

**Question:**
If I know I'm looking for the location of **data-beacon-article-modal="5ffe3f6fc64fe14d0e1fa33f"**, whether that's the 25th or 26th html element, what should my CSS selector look like based on above?

I attempted to just change div:nth-child(26) to div, but no luck. e.g.

```
#root > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.container > div > div > div > div > div.accrd-cont > p:nth-child(1) > a[data-beacon-article-modal*="5ffe3f6fc64fe14d0e1fa33f"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that that data attribute is unique try simply:

```
 a[data-beacon-article-modal="5ffe3f6fc64fe14d0e1fa33f"]
```

see for example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

> The CSS attribute selector matches elements based on the presence or value of a given attribute.

If it's unique you shouldn't need to express the selector going right back to root.